# regex sub with pattern reference

Tags: python, regex

lets say I have the following string:

```
s = """hi my name is 'Ryan' and I like to 'program' in "Python" the best"""
```

I would like to run a `re.sub` that would change the following string to:

```
"""hi my name is '{0}' and I like to '{1}' in "{2}" the best"""
```

This would let me save content, but have a reference to it so that I could add the original content back in.

**note:** I use the following code to grab all of the items in quotes so I would loop through this to make reference to the numbers

```
items = re.findall(r'([\'"])(.*?)\1',s)
```

**So how can I make it so the sub will recognize the number instance so I can create this kind of reference?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with callback:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import re
>>> s = """hi my name is 'Ryan' and I like to 'program' in "Python" the best"""
>>> c = itertools.count(1)
>>> replaced = re.sub(r'([\'"])(.*?)\1', lambda m: '{0}{{{1}}}{0}'.format(m.group(1), next(c)), s)
>>> print(replaced)
hi my name is '{1}' and I like to '{2}' in "{3}" the best
```

Used [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to generate numbers:

```
>>> it = itertools.count(1)
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
2
>>> next(it)
3
```

Comment: I have to go to a class now, but i'll accept your answer when I get back in a couple hours

Comment: if I wanted to use other symbols to wrap other than curly brackets, how do I? when I change the code to make it for `<` those kinds of brackets, i get the following error: `File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <lambda>
KeyError: '<1>'
`

Comment: Try `'{0}({1}){0}'`, `{0}*{1}*{0}`, .... Curly braces was escaped because of [`Format String Syntax`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).